# Does my iPhone send feedback based on who I block?

Tags: iphone

I block numbers from spam calls. Does this signal get sent to either my carrier or Apple to help them identify spammers?

Comment: Doubtful - how would they know the difference between a spam number & that of your ex- you just fell out with? Most territories have spam text reporting, usually a number that can be 'spelled' on an alpha-numeric dialler as SPAM [ie 7726]. idk if the same can be done for phone calls.

Comment: They can't know for sure, but if a number gets blocked by many different people then there's a high likelihood it's spam. I'm curious whether blocking is purely local or if that interaction is technically sharable (not prevented by Apple's privacy policy or technology limitations).

Comment: Some operators distribute software on AppStore that can show if a calling number may be spam. The app only get the number of the caller to check if it is in a list of suspicious number, dangerous or commercial numbers to display this on the phone screen. Their list may be updated by users who can signal these numbers. (Ex : for France : Orange Téléphone). On your phone blocked number are only local to your phone as operator can not know if it is blocked the phone redirects it to message box.